# Tsocks with mail user agent mailx not working

Tags: proxy, socks, mailx, tsocks

I use a SOCKS proxy server to send mail using `sendmail` in Linux and `mailx` to send mails from the command line.

To make use of the SOCKS server, I am using `tsocks` to send mails using `mailx`, for example like this

```
tsocks mailx -s "Test mail" valid_mail_address@gmail.com
```

But the mails I send are not going through the proxy. I don't know what I do wrong.

Any help please.

Comment: Could you paste the output of `tsocks mailx -v -s "Test mail" valid_mail_address@gmail.com` ? That would help understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect mailx is configured to use sendmail so tsocks is redundant here. What happens if you omit it?

tsocks may actually be in the way - if you don't have a rule in /etc/tsocks.conf to bypass the proxy for the loopback interface it could send the message to the proxy when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I just figured out how to send emails through the http/https only proxy:

Using only `ssmtp` and following the [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP) setup. The tutorial fails at the sending of the test mail, below is the solution which works for me.

I have a *ssh socks* connection to `localhost`. I'm using `corkscrew` to connect to my ssh daemon running on port 443. You may or may not need this. If you don't need this omit the `-o` option below

```
ssh -vv -CND 8080 -p443 user@<sshd server> -o "ProxyCommand corkscrew 
   $proxy_ip_or_domain_name $proxy_port <sshd server> 
   443 /file/to/proxy-credentials"
```

the proxy-credentials authorization file looks like this:

```
DOMAIN\user:pass
```

I have configured `/etc/tsocks.conf` like this

```
server = 127.0.0.1
server_port = 8080
```

The tutorial command

```
echo test | mail -v -s "testing ssmtp setup" username@somedomain.com
```

hangs and doesn't work for me when putting `tsocks` in front of it, but

```
TSOCKS_CONFFILE=/etc/tsocks.conf tsocks mail username@somedomain.com 
    < .bash_history
```

does.